# weird bump on object and dont know how to remove

Tags: objects, vertices

was following the BlenderGuru tutorial on making a coffee cup. was making the handle when i finished i noticed there was a small bump, pimple like, on my mug. the point its on seems to be in place. im not sure how to get rid or smooth it out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

nevermind! just fixed it. apparently i created another vertices inside the mug that was making it spike out. just deleted it!